# Joining two tables using left outer join and population a new column values based on the right table column

Tags: sql

I have two tables exam_table and emp_table, Here i would like to join both tables using left outer join and I want to create a new column called new_column using exam_completed_date column from the right table.

```
select id, exam_completed_date from exam_table;

id exam_completed_date 
0  12-01-2019
1  12-12-2019

select id, week_end_date from emp_table where id=0;

id week_end_date
0  11-29-2019
0  11-30-2019
0  12-31-2019
0  12-01-2019
0  12-02-2019
0  12-03-2019
0  12-04-2019

select id, week_end_date, exam_completed_date 
from emp_table emp left outer join 
     exam_table exam 
     on (exam.id=emp.id and exam.exam_completed_date=emp.week_end_date)
where id=0

id week_end_date exam_completed_date 
0  11-29-2019    
0  11-30-2019
0  12-31-2019
0  12-01-2019     12-01-2019
0  12-02-2019    
0  12-03-2019    
0  12-04-2019
```

I need output like this

```
id week_end_date exam_completed_date  new_column
0  11-29-2019    
0  11-30-2019
0  12-31-2019
0  12-01-2019     12-01-2019           12-01-2019
0  12-02-2019                          12-01-2019
0  12-03-2019                          12-01-2019 
0  12-04-2019                          12-01-2019
```

Comment: Please tag the only DBMS that you are really using.

Comment: My mistake .....Thanks for the suggestion Yogesh !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a cumulative max window function:

```
select id, week_end_date, exam_completed_date,
       max(exam_completed_date) over (partition by id order by week_end_date) as newcolumn
from emp_table emp left outer join
     exam_table exam 
     on exam.id=emp.id and
        exam.exam_completed_date = emp.week_end_date
where id = 0;
```

Comment: Thank You Gordon!! Thats an amazing solution.

Comment: I am getting '?' instead of null values

Comment: @DppriyaReddy . . . I don't know where those would be coming from.  Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.