# While creating a new column using partition by I am getting ? in the new columns data

Tags: sql, hive, window-functions

I have two tables exam_table and emp_table. Here I would like to join both tables using left outer join and I want to create a new column called new_column using exam_completed_date column from the right table

```sql
select id, exam_completed_date from exam_table;
```

```
id exam_completed_date 
0  12-01-2019
1  12-12-2019
```

```sql
select id, week_end_date from emp_table where id=0;
```

```
id week_end_date
0  11-29-2019
0  11-30-2019
0  12-31-2019
0  12-01-2019
0  12-02-2019
0  12-03-2019
0  12-04-2019
```

when I am joining two tables using left outer join i am getting ? in the data as shown below,

```sql
select id, week_end_date, exam_completed_date ,
max(exam_completed_date) over (partition by id order by week_end_date) as newcolumn
from emp_table emp left outer join 
     exam_table exam 
     on (exam.id=emp.id and exam.exam_completed_date=emp.week_end_date)
where id=0
```

```
id week_end_date exam_completed_date  new_column
0  11-29-2019          ?                  ?
0  11-30-2019          ?                  ?
0  12-31-2019          ?                  ?
0  12-01-2019     12-01-2019           12-01-2019
0  12-02-2019          ?               12-01-2019
0  12-03-2019          ?               12-01-2019 
0  12-04-2019          ?               12-01-2019
```

How can I go about eliminating `?` and replacing with null?

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882483/joining-two-tables-using-left-outer-join-and-population-a-new-column-values-base

Comment: I am using hive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using window function & which never return `?` unless you specify, you probably receives `null` values, so you can replace with `coalesce()`  :

```
coalesce(max(exam_completed_date) over (partition by id order by week_end_date), '')
```